# Least amount of syntatically correct characters to cause a Python exception

Tags: python, exception, syntax

It seems to cause an exception such as to do a quick and lazy coded abort in a program would not be to
`raise Exception`.  But during rapid development a better idiom might be to find a more convenient error:

You could do it even faster with 5 characters if you are well aware of `IndexError` being a placeholder with `[][0]`.

But one can do better with 4 characters with `[]-0` and yielding a `TypeError`.

Now we improve to 3 characters with `-[]` or `+[]` which is also a `TypeError`.  Variants of all of these with strings and tuples are possible.

Can syntactically valid code throw an exception with 2 or less characters in Python which is dependency-free and isolated?  This means no defining of variables, and works anywhere so not using any single letter variable names otherwise `a` would throw a `NameError` but obviously if the `a` variable were used in the program it would not work.

The least I could find was the 3 character combinations above which could be a really quick and short-hand development-time only way of aborting for merely quick testing of code.

Update: I came up with an idea to answer this exhaustively so I went ahead with it.  It is a bit of a code golf style question admittedly but it can be interesting nevertheless.

Comment: `π` causes a `NameError`  as long as nobody defines variables with unicode characters. (every single character name workd, too, obviously)

Comment: Not an answer for 2 characters, but for me the obvious solution for 3 characters is `1/0`.

Comment: There can be many 3 characters: `~1j`, `~''`, `*1,`

Comment: This smacks of code golf more than a practical question.

Answer (score 1):

To get a specific exception that you can track elsewhere you could define a single letter variable containing an instance of a custom exception class which raises itself when the invert operator is applied to it:

```
class CustomError(Exception): 

    def __invert__(self):
        raise self  

É = CustomError()  # Unlikely to be used elsewhere single letter variable.
```

usage:

```
~É  ==> raises a CustomError exception
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I realized this can be written in an exhaustive ASCII character enumeration program that is not only simple to write but evaluated by python.  However, the `_` keyword is apparently a special symbol in the python interpreted which is the result of the last expression, so this must be run in a fresh instance with no prior commands executed (beyond imports and function definitions)

```
def py_try(num):
  import itertools
  combs = {'TypeError':[], 'ZeroDivisionError':[]}
  for item in itertools.product(range(256), repeat=num):
    try:
      eval(bytes(item))
    except SyntaxError: pass
    except NameError: pass
    except ValueError: pass
    except Exception as e:
      print(e.__class__.__name__ + " " + bytes(item).decode("ascii"))
      combs[e.__class__.__name__].append(bytes(item).decode("ascii"))
  return combs
solution=py_try(3)
len(solution['ZeroDivisionError']) #20
len(solution['TypeError']) #168
```

2 characters never works.  But with 3 characters you get the following which for convenience are represented as regular expressions (grammar of only `[]|-`):

`[\-|+|~][\[\]|{}|\\|id|""|'']` - 18 possible combinations of `TypeError`.

any of `[0-9]/0` or `[0-9]%0` yields 10+10 combinations of `ZeroDivisionError`.

any of `~[0-9]j`, `*[0-9],` `~[0-9].` and `~.[0-9]` adds 10+10+10+10 more possibilities of `TypeError`.

any of `[0-9]@[0-9]` which yields 100 combinations of `TypeError`.

any of `[0-9]()` which gives 10 combinations each with a `SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?` before throwing a `TypeError`

So 20 `ZeroDivisionError` and 168 `TypeError` are possible.

Who would have thought so many as 188 guaranteed exception generating programs could be written in only 3 characters!

Comment: Nice work. But Python is not limited to ASCII and `range(256)` is not the ASCII range anyway because ASCII is 7 bit.

Comment: You are right, in fact its just using ASCII for single-byte encoding, its all 3 character combinations.  The invalid ASCII range is filtered out as ValueErrors in fact.